# No lights rendered in Eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, eevee-render-engine, linux

I'm very new to Blender and tried Blender 2.8.
My currently problem is that Eevee does not render the lights I placed in the scene as shown below:

[image: setup of my example]

The final render of Eevee:
[image: rendered with Eevee]

The weird thing is that it works with Cycles:
[image: rendered with Cycles]

In Eevee I enabled the options "Ambient Occlusion" and "Bloom".

Would be nice If someone could help me to render with Eevee :)

Edit:
Platform: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB
CPU: Intel i5 760

Solved by restarting blender (after computer was in standby)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working, make sure you have the latest 2.80.

[image]